# Is it possible to maintain state between Laravel requests?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I'm building a piece of middleware that takes an incoming request, looks up data based on the user-agent, and then modifies the request object data to include the newly looked-up data. I'd like to add light, in-memory caching of this data source that persists between requests. Is this possible with Laravel without using extra caching libraries?

My understanding is that the Laravel object is re-instantiated for each new request, so anything cached in memory will be wiped away after the Response is returned. Is there a way to do this? Am I just misunderstanding how Laravel handles new requests?

Comment: PHP is stateless. To archive this, laravel implements sessions. Sessions are shared just with the same user. If you want to share information between multiple user sessions, then you must use a cache (laravel already implement it, you just need to configure it)

Comment: Ah ok, this explains a lot. Thanks so much!